# get file name case sensitive

Tags: c

I read in an xml-file in c-code.
I get the filename of the xml-file from command line per user option. When my filename is for example "TestName.xml", it will also work, when the user gives "testname.xml" as command line option, because there's no case sensitivity.

But in my case, I have a problem with that. I want to generate a header file "TestName.h" out of the xml-file and as you see, the name should always be case senstive identical.

My problem is now, I use the text from the command line option and when the user types "testname.xml", the name of my header file will also have only lower cases.

I would like to have one of the following solutions:
1. I can somehow read the correct case sensitive filename, also when the user types it otherwise
2. fopen_s() should only work case sensitive

Solution 2 should only be an option, if there's no possibility for solution 1.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The answer would be quite different depending on your operating system. You might want to add that info to the question.

Comment: Look up the function stat(). If it's available, it might do what you want. Ultimately it depends on the OS however, if it allow case-insensitive filenames, the concept of "the real case" might be tricky.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 64Bit

Comment: Don't use the filename from the command line, use the name of the xml-file returned by e.g. `FindFirstFile` or `stat`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Karsten, in the mean time I found a solution, I think it is similar to your one:

```
std::string strSochIn("/path/text.xml");
WIN32_FIND_DATAA wfd;

HANDLE hFind = ::FindFirstFileA(strSochIn.c_str(), &wfd);
if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
  strSochIn = wfd.cFileName;
}
else
{
  //Error
}
```

I don't know what is the difference between FindFirstFile and FindFirstFileA, but I don't think there's much difference...